# Jquery not adding index to last row when creating a new row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please can someone tell me why the first row gets and index value of 1 but every other new row also get 1 instead of 2,3,4 and so on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Track</th>
                    <th scope="col">Album</th>
                    <th scope="col">Artist</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="track[0]" id="track"></td>
                    <td><input name="album[0]" id="album"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="artist[0]" id="artist">
                            <option value="">Please select</option>
                            <option value="1">Joe Bloggs</option>
                            <option value="2">Jack Bloggs</option>
                            <option value="3">Tina Bloggs</option>                              
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>

    <button>Add Row</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function($)
    {
        // trigger event when button is clicked
        $("button").click(function()
        {
            // add new row to table using addTableRow function
            addTableRow($("table"));
            // prevent button redirecting to new page
            return false;
        });

        function addTableRow(table)
        {   

            var $tr = $(table).find("tr:last").clone();
            alert($tr);
            var fname = $("#track").attr("name");
              var nid = fname.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
            var idx = nid[0];
            idx = idx.replace(/[[\]]/g,'')
            var n = fname.split("[");

            idx = parseInt(idx) + 1;
            $tr.find("input,select").attr("name", n[0] + "[" + idx + "]");

            $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);

        };
    });
    </script>       
</body>
```

I cant seem to work out how to add a new row every time increasing the "name" of each table element by 1 every time ready to use an AJAX post.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id. Cloning the row is fine but set the id of the inputs and select after doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new rows are being created wrong. Artist and Album elements **name** are always **track[0]**

Wouldn't be easier to do something like this?

```
function addTableRow(table) {

    var index = $(table).find("tbody tr").length;
    var $tr = $(table).find("tr:last").clone();
    $tr.find("input,select").each(function (i, k) {
        var old_name = $(k).attr("name");
        var new_name = old_name.replace(index-1, index);
        $(k).attr("name", new_name);
    });

    $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LQe9b/)

Also, consider to give a `class` instead of a id in every `input/select` and give a `id` to the row. It would be easier to work with. as **@HMR** said when cloning the `tr` the `inputs` and `select` id's are cloned as well, adding the row then causes multiple elements with the same id's. This is not good, **make sure each element as a unique ID**

Comment: though when cloning the tr the inputs and select id's are cloned as well, adding the row then causes multiple elements with the same id's. I suggest changing the id as well.

Comment: yes, I would give a class instead of a id in every td and give a id to the row. It would be easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new to JS, having spent so many years with PHP & ASP, I never needed to do much with JS other than find a script, copy & paste.  I'm now going to hit the JS books hard!!

Comment: first learn the principles of JS and then play with jQuery. jQuery framework will save you a lot of time when developing javascript applications

Answer (score 0):

How about just counting `tr` in the `tbody` instead:

```
    function addTableRow(table)
    {   
        var $tr = table.find("tbody").find("tr").last().clone();
        var fname = $("#track").attr("name");
        var nid = fname.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
        var new_idx = table.find('tbody').find('tr').length;
        var n = fname.split("[");

        idx = parseInt(idx) + 1;
        $tr.find("input,select").attr("name", n[0] + "[" + new_idx + "]");

        $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);

    };
```